# How to measure strength increases for supersets?

Tags: strength, bodybuilding, assessment

I know how to [calculate one rep max](http://www.exrx.net/Calculators/OneRepMax.html). I can calculate my one rep max and compare it to its previous values to find out if I have gained strength or not.

I'd like to do the same thing for supersets. How can I arrive at a (scalar) metric that will allow me to compare my strength change for a superset?

(I am following a HIT weight training program, very low volume, low frequency, high intensity, anaerobic.)

Comment: What's a strength change for a superset? Do you want to calculate your 1RM by only doing a superset, or do you want to calculate your "maximum superset", whatever that means, or are you looking for some sort of benchmark to compare your "three rounds of ten 135 pound squats followed by five pull-ups for time" performance over time?

Comment: Have you tried the old school way of doing it? Like actually performing the exercise and writing down the weight you used? Supersets would be very difficult to calculate ... You need to take a few things in consideration such as the person's endurance, strength, exercises performed before that and so on ...

Comment: @Alex: I log all my workouts. I know I can do an extra set to failure and calculate my 1RM but I'm looking for a way to figure out a combined 1RM or something like that using the superset reps & weights. So my question is more mathematical/statistical than exercise science related.

Comment: What is the validity of this measurement? I mean supersets change, is it the same muscle group superset, or opposing muscle groups (bb chest/db chest or chest/back). The significance of this is going to be frivolous unless you are keeping that same set/rep/weight and only increasing over a period of time long enough to actually record this and your body doesn't just say this is too easy but i'm not working any harder. I would focus on your 1RM. A superset max is ridiculous, and in 4 weeks you're going to be on a different exercise set anyway...

Comment: One rep max calculations are useless. If you are really interested to what your 1 rep max looks like. Then I suggest starting the superset with an one rep max every time.